# Can`t align Android Material 3 Toolbar title start|center_vertical

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, android-appbarlayout, material3

I want to have Toolbar title gravity `start|center_vertical`
Expected result :
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSdr0.png)

But actual result is :
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJyid.png)
Steps to reproduce:

- I'm creating View class and extending `MaterialToolbar`

  class AppBarSample @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyleAttr: Int = 0
  ) : MaterialToolbar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

  ```
   private var iconType: IconType? = null

   init {
       context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
           attrs,
           R.styleable.AppBarSample,
           defStyleAttr,
           R.style.Sample_Theme_App_AppBar
       ).apply {
           try {
               iconType =
                   getEnum(
                       R.styleable.AppBarSample_navIcon,
                       IconType.BACK
                   )
           } finally {
               recycle()
           }
       }
       setNavIcon()
   }

   private fun setNavIcon() {
       iconType?.apply {
           navigationIcon = when (this) {
               IconType.BACK -> ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_name)
               IconType.CLOSE -> ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_close)
           }
       }
   }

   enum class IconType {
       BACK, CLOSE
   }

   private inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> TypedArray.getEnum(index: Int, default: T) =
       getInt(index, -1).let {
           if (it >= 0) enumValues<T>()[it] else default
       }
  ```

  }
- My theme file

  ```
      <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="Theme.MaterialUISample" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
      ...
   </style>

   <style name="Sample.Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
       <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark.ActionBar</item>
   </style>

   <style name="Sample.Theme.App.AppBar" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar">
       <item name="navigationIcon">@null</item>
       <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
       <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Material3.ActionBar.Title</item>
   </style>
  ```
- setting `android:theme` from xml

  ```
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/Sample.Theme.App.AppBar"
      app:title="Post"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  ```

P.S I don't want to use `app:titleMarginTop=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your layout.

```
  app:titleCentered="true"
```